# date.day() returns TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: date, datetime, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm stuck. It appears that day is being overwritten as an int somewhere. But where? Where is day becoming an int?

```
from datetime import *

start_date = date(1901, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2000, 12, 31)
sundays_on_1st = 0

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):

    # type(single_date) => <type 'datetime.date'>
    # type(date.day()) => TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable
    # type(single_date.day()) => TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
    # ಠ_ಠ 

    if single_date.day() == 1 and single_date.weekday() == 6: 
        sundays_on_1st += 1                                     

print sundays_on_1st
```

Comment: Please *do* include the traceback; it is hard to guess where the error may lie without it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.day` is not a method, you do not need to call it. Only `.weekday()` is a method.

```
if single_date.day == 1 and single_date.weekday() == 6: 
    sundays_on_1st += 1
```

This works just fine:

```
>>> for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
...     if single_date.day == 1 and single_date.weekday() == 6:
...         sundays_on_1st += 1
... 
>>> print sundays_on_1st
171
>>> type(single_date.day)
<type 'int'>
```

From the [`datetime.date` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.day):

> Instance attributes (read-only):
>
> `date.year`
>   Between `MINYEAR` and `MAXYEAR` inclusive.
>
> `date.month`
>   Between 1 and 12 inclusive.
>
> `date.day`
>   Between 1 and the number of days in the given month of the given year.

It is implemented as a data descriptor (like a `property`) to make it read-only, hence the `TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable` error you saw.