# I am getting an error while trying to call datetime.date.day()

Tags: python, datetime, program-entry-point

I get this traceback error below when I run the following code:

```
from datetime import date

def main():
    today = date.day()
    print("today is ", today)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

**error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/CODE X/loops/super_hero_mix.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Documents/CODE X/loops/super_hero_mix.py", line 4, in main
    today = date.day()
TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [date.day() returns TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885881/date-day-returns-typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you wanted to use `date.today()`:

```
from datetime import date

def main():
    today = date.today()
    print("today is ", today)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

**Output:**

```
today is  2021-09-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date.today()` to get today's date. If you need the day of the month, use `date.today().day`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get today's date, you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    today = datetime.now().date()
    print("today is ", today)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

If it's the day of the month you're after:

```
from datetime import datetime 
datetime.now().date().day
```

If it's the day of the week you are after, then use:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%A"))
```